# How can I test an idle timer with ERT?

Tags: ert, testing, idle-timer

Say I have a function that is called on an idle timer:

```
(defun tmp:create () (mkdir "test"))
(run-with-idle-time 3 nil #'tmp:create)
```

How can I test that this function works?

Using something like

```
(ert-deftest async () ""
  (should-not (file-exists-p "test"))
  (sleep-for 4)
  (should (file-exists-p "test")))
```

doesn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Idle timers won't be touched until the call stack has been cleared, so sitting won't actually help, it is only once all execution has stopped with the timer be run, so in your case, the idle timer won't run until 3 seconds of idle time after your whole test has run.

To combat this, you can call `ert-run-idle-timers` from `ert-x.el` in your test.

Comment: That function doesn't seem to exist :( (24.4)

Comment: load-library `ert-x`, sorry didn't specify that.